# "FB is no defined" inside window.fbAsyncInit

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm implement a editor that can dynamic add the facebook like button, So I write this code:

```
utils.insertFacebookSdkJs = function (win) {
    var document = win.document;

    win.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'app id', // App ID
            version:'v2.0',
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; //js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_CN/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
};

$('#add').click(function(){
    //add <div class="fb-like"></div>
    utils.insertFacebookSdkJs(window);
});
```

When user click the add button, this function will be called. But it throw error: 'FB is not defined'.

Update: At utils.insertFacebookSdkJs function, I found if i pass top window object to parameter 'win', the FB object is fine. But i pass iframe window object to parameter 'win', the FB object is not defined.

**Update:** Problem have solved. Because the facebook button in a iframe. So the FB object is a field in iframe window. Just fix FB to win.FB at utils.insertFacebookSdkJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version:

```
utils.insertFacebookSdkJs = function () {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'app id', // App ID
            version:'v2.0',
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; //js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
};

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    utils.insertFacebookSdkJs();
});
```

Removed unneccessary variables and changed locale (for testing). Also avoided jQuery because you should not use it for basic stuff like click listeners imho.

I am doing pretty much the same in my projects, so if it does not work i expect the error to be at a different spot and a test link may be necessary.

Comment: That's great! It can work. But i can't removed the 'win' variales. Because i need add Facebook like button in a iframe. So i need call such as utils.insertFacebookSdkJs(iframeWindow)

Comment: And I found if variables 'win' is top window, the FB is fine. But if variables 'win' is iframe window, the FB is not defined. How can i solve it?

Comment: i am using this on a regular basis in iframes on facebook and never had any problems. "windows" should be the actual window, not top - so if done correctly, you will not need those variables.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The FB object not indicate the correctly window in my code. And i already solve it. Thank you very much!